# Codeigniter - session data won't set

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, web-development-server

I have an issue setting session data. I want to set the session data to a boolean 'loggedIn' and an id 'userID'. For some reason when submitting the login form, the login() function will reach the line where it redirects to the dashboard() function, but then stops at the dashboard function.

**Controllers**

```
    public function login() {
//  echo 'login page';
        $this->session->set_userdata('userID', NULL);
        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', NULL);

        $data['session_data'] = array(
            'userID' => $this->session->userdata('userID'),
            'loggedIn' => $this->session->userdata('loggedIn')
        );

        $this->load->view('navigation');
        $this->load->view('login', $data);

        if ($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'please log out to access this page ');
            echo 'Please log out to access this page!...';
            sleep(2);
            redirect('index.php/user/dashboard');
        }

        if ($this->input->post('login')) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');

            $login_details = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('sucess_msg', 'form running ');
                $verify_password = $this->user_model->verify_password($login_details);

                if ($verify_password == true) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'password verified true ');
                    $userID = $this->user_model->get_userID($login_details);

                    $data_session = array(
                        'loggedIn' => TRUE,
                        'userID' => $userID
                    );

                    $session_loggedIn = array('loggedIn' => TRUE);
                    $session_userID = array('userID' => $userID);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', $session_loggedIn);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $session_userID);

                    //$this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', $data_session['loggedIn']);
                    //$this->session->set_userdata('userID', $data_session['userID']);
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'loggedIn and userID changed to current log in account ');

                    echo 'USER ID: ' . $this->session->userdata('userID');
                    //$this->load->view('dashboard', $);
                    redirect('index.php/user/dashboard');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'wrong email or password, try again!...');
                    //redirect('index.php/user/login');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function dashboard() {

        if ($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'please log in to access the dashboard page');
            sleep(2);
            redirect('index.php/user/login');
        } else {
            $data['user'] = array(
                'user' => $this->user_model->get_user_data($this->session->userdata('userID'))
            );

            $this->load->view('navigation');
            $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
        }
    }
```

**Models**

```
public function verify_password($login_details){
  $this->db->select('password');
  $this->db->from('user_account');
  $this->db->where('username', $login_details['username']);
  $query = $this->db->get->result_array();

  if($query[0] == $login_details['password']){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

}

**Config**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

**Result**

```
session data: Array ( [userID] => [loggedIn] => ) 
session data: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1522538883 [userID] => [loggedIn] => )
```

The program will reach the first condition of the dashboard function and then redirect back to the login page because it says that the session data 'loggedIn' is not set to TRUE.

Comment: @Arvind I have my sessions saving to a folder, and the expiration is set to 7200.

Comment: on the top on function you have `$this->session->set_userdata('userID', NULL);` and `$this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', NULL);` not sure why you have null on set_userdata try and remove that

Comment: @user4419336 That was there for some testing while trying to figure out what was wrong. I've removed it and tried again but the problem is still the same

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: and post your session config variables please!

Comment: @Alex I have updated the question with the config. I should also mention that session files are being created, but no data is being set. The session fields seem to be created, but no data is being saved to them. I find this strange that the 'loggedIn' field won't set to TRUE.

Comment: edit the functions to mirror this: https://pastebin.com/fwv4bPmc for debugging. let me know *exactly* what the output is

Comment: The result: NULL
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1522545497
    [userID] => 
    [loggedIn] => 
)

Comment: __ci_last_regenerate|i:1522545497;userID|N;loggedIn|N;      <----- is what is stored in the session file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167964/discussion-between-alex-and-chris-mulheron).

Comment: edit your question with the model function for verify password.

Comment: @user4419336 I have added the model. Although I don't understand how that would be the issue if the session variable 'loggedIn' won't set to true like all other examples online.

Comment: The sessions will set outside of running the form, but will not set during. So when the program reaches the verify_password == true condition (which it successfully does), $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', 'true') ; does not set any data.